# Echo php function and json in javascript

Tags: json, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter. I want to get the base_url() and json data so i can retrieve the image url. But how can i compile the base_url() and the json.

Below is what i tried but not working

```
        var url = <?php echo base_url(); ?>;
        var image = document.write(url + obj[0].picture);
```

@tom's comment is my answer.

Comment: You'll need to wrap the url variable value in quotes `var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";`

Comment: ok, i think i got the answer from @tommarshall

Comment: His answer works if there are no special characters in the url.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher How to say that?

Comment: tommarshall's answer worked in this situation.  The answer I gave, however, word work anytime you needed to convert a `PHP` string to a string `Javascript`  For instance the string `She said, "Ain't that cute."`  That string has double quotes in it, so sending it to Javascript needs extra handling.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` will convert the `base_url()`, however -- you don't need to do that.

If you don't specify otherwise, URLs are automatically relative to the current document's URL.

Comment: ops sorry, i forgot to mention obj[0].picture is retrieve from my db.
obj[0].picture = public/images/abc.jpg
then
base_url() = http://localhost/codeigniter/

i want to compile them so
http://localhost/codeigniter/public/images/abc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap the url variable value in quotes var `url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";`

(Copied from earlier comment so that the question can be marked as closed)

This is the most simple way of passing PHP variable values to JavaScript which works for strings. You can (and should) use json_encode for more complex variables values like arrays.

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.google.com';
    $foo = array('apple', 'banana', 'melon', array('a', 'b', 'c'));
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "<?php echo $url; ?>";
    var foo = <?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>;
</script>
```